# Number keyboard without pattern in angular

Tags: html, angular, regex, input, ngx-mask

I'm using [NgX-Mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) to mask my input box. I want to include special characters in the mask so i have used `[dropSpecialCharacters]="false"` from the NgXMask.

Because of angular validation it showing red indicator as pattern is not matched. Pattern currently using `\d*`

```
<input pattern="\d*" [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" mask="H0:00" placeholder="HH:MM" required
class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" name="inputValue" />
```

**Acceptance Criteria** 
  1 In Safari it should show number keyboard by default. (input pattern="\d*") which shows number keyboard by default.

**Expected Result** 
I want to include the ':' character to the pattern so it shows green indicator

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyv9jj)

App Supported : IPad Only

**Update**
This pattern will match my input `^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$` 

**but how will i bring the Number keyboard**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which solve both my problem.

Used [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/) and another [RexExTool](https://regexr.com/) for RegEx Helpers.

Used this regEx to validate my input 
`^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$`

Used **input mode to numeric** for number keyboard in IPad.
`inputmode="numeric"`

```
 <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$"
  [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" mask="H0:00" placeholder="HH:MM" required
  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" name="inputValue" />
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxbvu9)  
 1. This first text box with invalid value and text keyboard 
 2. The second text box with valid input and number keyboard